# Object oriented design - when to use getClass and instanceof

Tags: java, oop

During university lecture lecturer said that using `getClass` and `instanceof` indicates a bad design.

What are example usages that are bad design? What problems can be caused by using these methods? Are there any valid usages of these methods, which are not bad design?

Comment: every overloaded equals() method is using instanceOf or getClass, so i dont see that using these is a bad design .

Comment: @EdwinJarosiński I cannot think of many more valid cases. I have seen plenty of code where `instanceof` was used in multiple if statements to decide what code to execute depending on input parameter, etc. And this is bad design.

Comment: hmm ... thats rigth in other cases is bad design. I dont want to meet people who do things like checking input parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Poor usages

I would say that it's a sign of bad design in most cases. For example, let's say that you have a list of objects and you are doing `instanceof`, followed by the cast, followed by calling a method specific for the class. Instead, these objects should have common superclass and the method should be declared there - then different code will be executed depending on the actual type of object (since subclass may define different implementation).

```
private static class A {
    private void printA() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

private static class B {
    private void printB() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> list = asList(new A(), new B(), new A());

    list.forEach(element -> { // this is bad, don't do it!
        if (element instanceof A) {
            ((A) element).printA();
        }
        if (element instanceof B) {
            ((B) element).printB();
        }
    });
}
```

Instead, you should do this:

```
private interface Printer {
    void print();
}

private static class A implements Printer {
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

private static class B implements Printer  {
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Printer> list = asList(new A(), new B(), new A());

    list.forEach(Printer::print);
}
```

## Good usages

#### Equals method

A valid use case you will see in autogenerated `equals` methods. Before actually comparing objects, there is a check whether they are of the same class. If they are not, they cannot be equal so there is a fail-fast optimisation. This is actually enforced by `equals` method taking a parameter of type `Object`. Even if two objects we are comparing are actually equal, we will have to cast the parameter and before doing this we should check its class in order to return `false` rather then getting `ClassCastException`.

Equals method generated by IntelliJ:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Person person = (Person) o;

        if (!name.equals(person.name)) return false;
        return surname.equals(person.surname);
    }
}
```

#### Tools using reflection API

Another valid case of using these methods is for example when creating various tools such as POJO to json mappers, which can be done only via reflection API.

**EDIT:**

Following your questions in comments, here is the working example of how to implement a list of animals, where dog can run and eagle can both run and fly:

```
public static abstract class Animal {

    protected final String name;

    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(name + " runs");
    }

    public abstract void move();
}

public static class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog() {
        super("Dog");
    }

    @Override
    public void move() {
        run();
    }
}

public static class Eagle extends Animal {

    public Eagle() {
        super("Eagle");
    }

    public void fly() {
        System.out.println(name + " flies");
    }

    @Override
    public void move() {
        fly();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Animal> animals = Arrays.asList(new Dog(), new Eagle());

    animals.forEach(Animal::move);

    System.out.println("Eagle can run too!");
    new Eagle().run();
}
```

Output:

```
Dog runs
Eagle flies
Eagle can run too!
Eagle runs
```

It is all about analysing how the code is used and extracting common parts. If in the loop you were always ordering animal to run, then the cast would not be needed since `run()` is declared on `Animal`. Here on the other hand we want animal to move, doesn't matter how, so let them choose their default movement type by creating abstract `move()` method in `Animal` class.

Comment: That's a great answer! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can it be avoided it in the following case: Animal is a an abstract class with fields: name, groundSpeed and run as an abstract method. We have Dog class has same fields and run method. In addition, we have Eagle class, that also has a flyingSpeed field. Eagle has an implementation of run method and fly Method.

Comment: @Niminim It all depends on how you actually use these objects.

Comment: Assuming I know that an object in the list is an animal. if he's a dog I want him to run, if it's an eagle I want him to fly. Just like you mentioned in the beginning of your answer.

Comment: @Niminim So even though eagle can both run and fly, you don't make it run, you make it fly. This means that you can create `move` method in `Animal` - `Dog` will delegate it to `run`, while `Eagle` will delegate it to `fly`. And then you just call `move` on the animal, regardless of what animal it really is.

Comment: Good idea. And if eagles run in case no other animal is within it's eyesight, and otherwise they fly ?

Comment: The implementation will still be in move, right ?  move in eagle decides whether it should fly or run, right ?

Comment: Let me add an example in the answer.

Comment: ok, sounds like a good idea

Comment: Thanks!  Then move in eagle (with the right logic) decides whether the eagle will fly (the eagle spotted an animal) or run (the eagle hasn't spotted an animal in it's vicinity), just like I thought. Thanks a lot !! your answer is really helpful :)

Comment: Exactly. I didn't actually think about adding logic to `move()` when writing it :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in well designed code you wouldn't need to do this. Most often where it does happen it's because you are interacting with objects that you can't change but need to have different behavior based on them.

For example if the animals from Jaroslaw Pawlak's example were provided by a third party library that you couldn't change and you now needed to add a new behaviour (for example animals with injured legs that can no longer run but can fly) then using instanceof might be the only way to make that happen.

The result is often terrible architecture and you would not do it that way in the ideal world, but sometimes it's the only way to get the result you need.

I've also used it in Swing GUIs for example, I have a number of different controls in a JPanel and I'm scanning through the list and calling different methods depending on the type of the control. The alternative would be to either keep lists of specific types of controls and/or write wrappers and keep lists of those wrappers. Either approach adds a lot more book-keeping and overhead and making sure the lists are synchronized at all times can cause strange errors in future (for example if you add a control and forget to add it to the list to scan).

Comment: Good point about external libraries. To give you another real-world example, I was recently using NetSuite's SuiteTalk, a SOAP web service API. It has conceptually a Transaction class with subclasses Invoice, CustomerRefund, CashDeposit, etc. Except they are not actually related in the Java class definitions. They all have common methods, such as getTranId(). To write a method that takes any transaction type and prints its transaction id requires you to use reflection, since you can't call getTranId() polymorphically.

Comment: Thanks Tim and klitos ! I haven't used any third party library yet, but I'm sure this insight will be more relevant in the future.